# MSSQL Creating and loading data

Tags: sql-server, loading

I'm interested to hear other developers views on creating and loading data as the current site I'm working on has a completely different take on DWH loading.

The protocol used currently to load a fact table has a number of steps;

1. Drop old table
2. Recreate Table with no PK/Clustered Index
3. Load cleaned/new data
4. Create PK & Indexes

I'm wondering how much work really goes on under the covers with step 4?  The data are loaded without a Clusterd index so I'm assuming that the natural order of the data load defines its order on disk.  When step 4. creates a primary key (clustered) it will re-order the data on disk into that order.  Would it not be better to load the data and have the PK/Clustered Index already defined thereby reduce server workload?

Comment: Only if the data is already ordered in the same order as the index. Otherwise the index would have to be updated constantly

Comment: @RichBenner that's not correct. A clustered index affects the actual storage order of the rows. The rows do get moved

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for updating me, i've deleted the incorrect comment.

Answer (score 0):

When `inserting` a large amount of records, the overhead in updating the index can often be larger than simply creating it from scratch.  The performance gain comes from `inserting` onto a heap which is the most efficient way to get data into a table.

The only way you can know if your import strategy is faster with the indexes left intact, will be to test both on your own environment and compare.

Answer (score 0):

Up to my thoughts Indexers are Good for Select. and may be bad for DML operations.

And if you are loading the Huge amount of  data that means you need to update Indexers for every insert. This may lag the performance. Some times it may go beyond the limit.